# Simple argument to generalize an identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an invertible, definite positive, $n\times n$ matrix.

**An exercise states that :**

$(A^{-1})_{ii}=(A_{ii}-\sum_{j,k=1, j\neq i, k\neq 1}^NA_{ij}((A^{(i)})^{-1})_{jk}A_{ki})^{-1}$ where $A^{(i)}$ denotes the matrix $A$ stripped from its i-th line and column vector.

It says it is related to Schur's complement lemma, which I don't know about.

**If I know a proof for $i=n$, what's a smart way to generalize for every $i$ without additional calculations ?** Maybe it's as trivial as making a basis change $e_i \leftrightarrow e_n$, but it's not obvious to me...

I would like to find an elementary proof of this.

[**A possible proof for the case $i=n$ is easily obtained considering a block matrix :**](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/papers/laura-thesis.pdf)

$A=\begin{bmatrix}A^{(n)}&X\\Y&A_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$

$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}B^{(n)}&Z\\T&B_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$

Since $AA^{-1}=\mathbb{Id}$, we have that :

$A^{(n)}Z+XB_{nn}=0$, so $Z=-A^{(n)^{-1}}XB_{nn}$

and

$YZ+A_{nn}B_{nn}=1=A_{nn}B_{nn}-YA^{(n)^{-1}}XB_{nn}$

Leading to :

$(A^{-1})_{nn}=B_{nn}=(A_{nn}-YA^{(n)^{-1}}X)^{-1}$

which corresponds to the exercise statement for the case $i=n$.

I guess it could be possible to deduce the generalized formula with the same method, but this would mean working with $3\times3$ matrices, so tedious calculations... and I have a feeling that the generalized form can be deduced from the $i=n$ proof easily.

Any idea on how to proceed from there ?